# iOS tabBar button gets wrong background color

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard

I have a custom tabBar in my Swift app that displays fine on all tested devices except one (iPhone 5 running iOS 9.3.2), where the selected item gets a different background color (see attached image). Any ideas what this might be caused by or how to debug it?

[image: tabBar icon with wrong background color]

[image: TabBar]

[image: TabBar Item]

**Update:**
Tried another iPhone 5 also running iOS 9.3.2, and the same issue showed up... The issue doesn't show up on iphone 5c, 5s,6, 6s, ipod touch or in the simulator.

Comment: I am up-voting your question because you correctly styled "iOS" in the title (lower case "i"), against all odds of it being the first word in the title. :-)

Comment: Haha thank you! Proper text formatting is just as important as code formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

It turned out not be a bug after all, but caused by the phone's accessibility settings:

Settings > General > Accessibility > setting Button Shapes to OFF

=> Buttons are no longer outlined like in the screenshot!